# Linking back from popup on devices

Tags: html, css, popup, mobile-devices

I build a simple page with popup links. Works fine on desktop.

I don't know how to solve an issue in a right way, i mean, i can find a crappy solution but i would like to know the correct one. On cell phone when clicking back from the popup image, its return to somewhere on the middle of the main page, not on the top of the page. This is an online sample to try:

[online page](http://danielillo.neocities.org/)

```css
html, a {text-decoration:none;}

div {margin:0 auto 10px auto; height:200px; width:200px}

h1 {font: normal 90px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
letter-spacing: 0.5px; 
line-height:1px; 
position: relative;
top:100px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
font-weight: 800;
color:#000000}


.popup {
position: absolute;
padding-top:30px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
text-align:center;
z-index: 200;
opacity:1;  
}

.popup:target {
display: block;
-webkit-animation-name: fadein 0,2s; 
animation-name: fadein;
animation-duration: 0.2s;
}
.popup img {
padding: 4px;
width: 80%;
z-index: 120;
border: solid 1px gray;
cursor: pointer;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
div {margin:0 auto 10px auto; height:200px; width:auto}

}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="gray">
<div class="button" style="background-color:#049EA4;"><a href="#01"><h1>01</h1></a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #F1FB00"><a href="#02"><h1>02</h1></a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #1779F0;"><a href="#03"><h1>03</h1></a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #FF00CF;"><a href="#04"><h1>04</h1></a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #FFA200;"><a href="#05"><h1>05</h1></a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #0042FF;"><a href="#06"><h1>06</h1></a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #A01CF0;"><a href="#07"><h1>07</h1></a>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #0DF186;"><a href="#08"><h1>08</h1></a>
</div>


<div id="01" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/pekann%C3%B6t-plant-pot-rattan__0132102_pe286857_s4.jpg" alt="01"></a></div>

<div id="02" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/or%C3%A4dd-plant-pot-in-outdoor-beige__0108864_pe258535_s4.jpg" alt="02"></a></div>

<div id="03" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/socker-plant-pot-in-outdoor-galvanised__0107648_pe257427_s4.jpg" alt="03"></a></div>

<div id="04" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/huson-plant-pot__12045_PE089408_S4.JPG" alt="04"></a></div>

<div id="05" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/ingef%C3%A4ra-plant-pot-with-saucer-outdoor-terracotta__0313254_pe513840_s4.jpg" alt="05"></a></div>

<div id="06" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/ragkorn-plant-pot__0134053_PE289885_S4.JPG" alt="06"></a></div>

<div id="07" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/skurar-plant-pot-in-outdoor-off-white__0114580_pe267097_s4.jpg" alt="07"></a></div>

<div id="08" class="popup"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.ikea.com/us/en/images/products/hasselnot-plant-pot__0119553_PE275934_S4.JPG" alt="08"></a></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your image is popping up at the bottom of your page, so when you close the image, you're looking at the bottom of the page.

To make your popup appear at the top of the page, add `top: 0;` to your `.popup` class:

```
.popup {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
padding-top:30px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
text-align:center;
bgcolor:yellow;
z-index: 200;
opacity:1;  
}
```